# how to convert the http to https the facebook app

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, facebook, iis

I develop the facebook app, it default as http.My admin taken the ssl certificate for the https,he done the his work on iis 7.0 .
now browse the my facebook app,it works in http mode.
but it did not work properly in the https.
i calling the response from ajax through js,response is not getting ajax to my app.
i wrote the path as "http://",
how to call the "https".

**my app will be work in both http and https**.

please give the your value words for me.
  thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: response didnot get ajax page to js.

Comment: Ok, so what do you expect and what do you get instead? (eg, White screen?)

Comment: i bind the data using stringbulider, i want that response data

Answer (score 1):

> i calling the response from ajax through js,response is not getting ajax to my app

For (normal) AJAX requests to work the domain, protocol and port have to match that of the page – it’s called *same origin policy*. If your page is called via HTTPS you can not make an AJAX request to the HTTP version of your domain.

> i wrote the path as "http://", how to call the "https".

Don’t specify the protocol at all, then the browser figures out by himself if he has to use http:// or https://

If you can’t use just a relative path, then give an absolute path without protocol – that is, `//example.com/foo/bar.php` instead of `http://example.com/foo/bar.php` (replace with your own domain, obviously).